# Query Design, Strange Results - New to SQL-Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've written a query that's producing ghost records. Here's the statements which produce correct results on one table JOINed to a second table to grab the student's `LAST_ATTEND_DATE`, notice the `LAST_ATTEND_DATE` won't display, commented out:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 500
  SAC.STC_PERSON_ID AS CCID#,
  SAC.STC_COURSE_NAME AS CourseName,
  SAC.STC_TITLE AS Title,
  SAC.STC_VERIFIED_GRADE AS Grade,
  --CONVERT(varchar(10),SCS.SCS_LAST_ATTEND_DATE,101) AS LastAttended,
  SAC.STC_REPORTING_TERM AS Term,
  SAC.STC_ACAD_LEVEL AS AcadLevel
FROM STUDENT_ACAD_CRED SAC
JOIN STUDENT_COURSE_SEC SCS ON SAC.STC_PERSON_ID = SCS.SCS_STUDENT
WHERE (SAC.STC_ACAD_LEVEL = 'UG') AND (SCS.SCS_LAST_ATTEND_DATE IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY SAC.STC_PERSON_ID;
```

This produces what I need except I need to display in the resulting data the students Last Attended Date. If I un-comment the statement above to display the `LAST_ATTEND_DATE`, 4 records appear in which 2 are ghost records. For example student ID = '0000002', he took English 1010 once in the Fall of 1992, made a D, then retook the course again in the Fall of 1993 and made a B.

```
 0000002  ENGL*1010   English I   D   92/FA   UG
 0000002  ENGL*1010   English I   B   93/FA   UG
```

With the `LAST_ATTEND_DATE` statement (`CONVERT(varchar(10),SCS.SCS_LAST_ATTEND_DATE,101) AS LastAttended`) un-commented to display the date, then 3 additional records appear...

I've tried changing the query between the 2 tables from JOIN, to LEFT JOIN, FULL JOIN and RIGHT JOIN. I always get 3 additional records that don't exist.

```
 0000002   ENGL*1010   English I   B   01/19/1995   93/FA   UG
 0000002   ENGL*1010   English I   B   07/18/1996   93/FA   UG
 0000002   ENGL*1010   English I   B   09/25/1992   93/FA   UG
 0000002   ENGL*1010   English I   D   01/19/1995   92/FA   UG
 0000002   ENGL*1010   English I   D   07/18/1996   92/FA   UG
```

Would anyone know the correct syntax to JOIN these 2 tables correctly to display the data correctly?

Thanks so much for sharing your knowledge,

Donald, Casper College

Comment: Theres nothing wrong with the syntax per se. It is likely that you may need to gain more familiarity with the model - the records that you are terming as "ghost" may be records that are relevant to queries other than yours and could be eliminated in the `WHERE` clause if you knew which field to focus on. Very hard to help you on this one as the model is not exposed to us.

Comment: +1 for good presentation.  Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Refraining from a joke about Casper and ghosts...

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the Student_Course_Sec table contains more than one record per student, which your `join` statement is not accounting for.

For example, if the SCS table consists of:

```
SCS_Student    SCS_CourseName    SCS_LastAttendDate
1              English           1/1/2014
1              Calculus          2/1/2014
2              English           3/1/2014
2              Philsolphy        4/1/2014
```

And your SAC table consists of:

```
STC_PERSON_ID  STC_COURSE_NAME  etc.
1              English
1              Calculus
2              English
2              Philosophy
```

then when you `SELECT * FROM SAC JOIN SCS ON SAC.STS_PERSON_ID = SCS.SCS_STUDENT`, your result set looks like this:

```
(row) STC_ID STC_Course SCS_ID SCS_Course SCS_Date
1     1      English    1      English    1/1/2014
2     1      English    1      Calculus   2/1/2014
3     1      Calculus   1      English    1/1/2014
4     1      Calculus   1      Calculus   2/1/2014
5     2      English    2      English    3/1/2014
6     2      English    2      Philosophy 4/1/2014
7     2      Philosophy 2      English    3/1/2014
8     2      Philosophy 2      Philosophy 4/1/2014
```

Your `WHERE` clause then filters out all the rows where `STC_COURSE` is not "English", leaving you with 4 rows (row numbers 1,2,5,6) instead of just the 2 you really want (rows 1 and 5).  (And, because you're not reporting any of the other fields, it just looks like "phantom records" appear out of nowhere.)

To fix it, you need additional conditions on your JOIN specifying what else besides the ID needs to match up.  In my contrived case, you would need to say
`JOIN STUDENT_COURSE_SEC SCS on SAC.STS_PERSON_ID = SCS.SCS_STUDENT and SAC.STC_COURSE_NAME = SCS.SCS_COURSE_NAME`, selecting only rows where both the student and the course are a proper match.

Answer (score 0):

The 'ghost' records are actually the true result set. The reason that they don't display when you comment out `SCS.SCS_LAST_ATTEND_DATE` is that you are creating duplicate records since the date is the only differentiator, and your `DISTINCT` is suppressing the duplicates.

If you remove the `DISTINCT`, and leave `SCS.SCS_LAST_ATTEND_DATE` commented out, you should then get the same number of rows as when you uncomment the date.

Playing around with the JOIN types implies that you don't really know what you are trying to query. As @MarkD said in the comments, we would need to see your data model in order to help you further.